# How can I automate the addition of a Nuget package source?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to automate the restoration of some custom Nuget packages, which are stored at a custom repository host. I've got the package installed locally, but a fresh developer machine will fail to restore these packages because it won't know about the custom NuGet repository if my understanding of the configuration is correct.

Adding a custom NuGet source is not a huge deal, but I'd really like to get everything so that the developer can build right after pulling from version control. Is there...

1. Any way to automate the addition of the custom NuGet repo as part of the source pull, i.e., is that stored anywhere in the source? Or...
2. Is there any way to designate the custom source in the package config?

Comment: Did you try including a NuGet.Config file with your source in version control? You can define custom package sources in that file. So there is no need to add extra package sources in Visual Studio. NuGet will look for a NuGet.Config file based on the solution directory and work its way back up the directories to the root. So if you add it to the root of the version control source code then all solutions in the tree should use the information defined there.

Comment: This may be the answer...but I thought they'd deprecated solution config in favor of machine-wide config.

Comment: I gave this a try, and it seems to work. If you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Using a NuGet.Config file alongside your solution is not deprecated as far as I am aware. There is documentation on how the settings in NuGet.config files are applied - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied